# How to keep router on page reload in Flutter web pwa

Tags: flutter

For example, I have a router `https://example.com/about` or `https://example.com/about/edit`
But when I reload the page, the router redirects to the init page using router `https://example.com`

This is extremely bad when the user wants to refresh the page
Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: I have yet to figure this out as well,. but i currently have a plan to always store the current route locally, and then on reload check if that exists and load that route.